# Is there a more memory efficient way to concatenate two columns in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks, sparkr

I'm trying to concatenate two columns from two spark data frames using SparkR e.g.

Frame1

| ID | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |

Frame2

| OtherID | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 |

After concatenation:

| ID | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 | 0 |
| 23 | 1 | 0 |
| 34 | 1 | 1 |
| 45 | 0 | 1 |
| 56 | 1 | 1 |

As these are Spark frames, each column is treated as a S4 class, rather than a vector so attempting a simple `paste(Frame1$ID, Frame2$OtherID)` doesn't work as R can't coerce the S4 type into a vector. My current solution then, is to collect the two frames into regular R dataframes and then run the paste command:

```
r_frame1 <- collect(Frame1)
r_frame2 <- collect(Frame2)

r_frame1$id <- paste(r_frame1$ID, rframe2$OtherID, sep = "")
```

This works for some of my data, however I need to do this for several tables, all of which are very large (several million rows) and I'm getting java.lang.outofmemory errors in my Databricks environment. Is there a more memory efficient way of doing this? Perhaps one that doesn't involve collecting into a R dataframe? I have also tried running it as a SQL command using CONCAT, but ran into some other issues (see my previous related question: [Databricks SQL CONCAT function adding characters where not requested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572551/databricks-sql-concat-function-adding-characters-where-not-requested?noredirect=1#comment129923295_73572551))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`concat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/R/concat.html):

```r
Frame1$id = concat(Frame1$ID, Frame2$OtherID)
```

I you want to concatenate with a separator you can use [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/R/concat_ws.html):

```r
Frame1$id = concat_ws('_', Frame1$ID, Frame2$OtherID)
```

Note that if your columns are integer, you probably need to cast them to string before the concatenation with something like that:

```r
Frame1$id = concat(cast(Frame1$ID, "string"), cast(Frame2$OtherID, "string"))
```